# How to install "sw20­jart.sty"?

Tags: packages, installing

I've search internet and found below code:

```
%sw20jart {Article: JEEP (a general purpose vehicle)}{12pt}{article}{empty}
%Copyright (C) 1994-95 TCI Software Research
\typeout{TCI Document Style `sw20jart' <1 July 1994>.}
\typeout{NOTICE:  This macro file is NOT proprietary and may be 
freely copied and distributed.}
%
\input{jeep.sty}
\input thmsupp.tex %TCI theorem option support
\cfoot{\thepage}%
\tighttoc%
\numberbysection%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
%
% The following is included to suppress page numbers on the first page
% when a title is used.
\def\maketitle{\par
 \begingroup
   \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
   \def\@makefnmark{\hbox
       to\z@{$\m@th^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}%
   \if@twocolumn
     \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
     \else \newpage
     \global\@topnum\z@
%     \@maketitle \fi\thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks  % Page number on first page
     \@maketitle \fi\thispagestyle{empty}\@thanks  % No page numbers
 \endgroup
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
 \let\maketitle\relax
 \let\@maketitle\relax
 \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}
```

Is it the package I'm searching for?
If Yes, How can I install it?

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for using this package?

Comment: @egreg I have some .tex files which written by this package.

Comment: My suggestion is to comment out the call of the package and see what happens.

Comment: @egreg It works. Although there was a command "\input{tcilatex}" which needs commenting out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sw20jart.sty` belongs to [Scientific WorkPlace (SWP)](https://www.mackichan.com) and, as far as I can see, it just does some (bad) redefinition of standard commands. It also loads [`jeep.sty`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex209/contrib/jeep/jeep.sty) that is a LaTeX 2.09 style file and which does similar bad redefinitions.

The file [`thmsupp.sty`](http://arxiv.org/macros/thmsupp.tex) does nothing at all: it just defines package options that are not used because of the way the file is loaded.

The `tcilatex.tex` file that's probably also loaded does nothing: it is a compatibility layer for SWP, that only influences the screen output on the front-end.

Thus you should be safe in commenting out both

```
\usepackage{sw20jart}
```

and

```
\input{tcilatex}
```

Maybe the output will be different from the original, but the important thing is, I guess, that the file can be processed without errors.